# Composer Airflow - Cross DAG Task Dependancy

Tags: google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I have below 2 DAGs and tasks

DAGA - Task1,Task2,Task3

DAGB - Task4,Task5,Task6

Now Task4 & 5 of DAG B depends on Task1 of DAGA and Task6 depends on Task3 but I want this dependency only on Monday and for remaining days I don't want this dependency.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of cross dag dependency wherein you want certain tasks of a dag to run on a particular day of the week , use [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/cross-dag-dependencies/) along with [BranchPythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.6/concepts.html?highlight=branch%20operator#branching). This operator function must return a list of task IDs that the DAG should proceed with based on some logic.

Another good [link](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-branch-operator/)